# "Parental Advisory: Explicit Content"

Tags: word-usage

Everyone is familiar with those warning labels that started in the late 80s warning that a piece of music has "Explicit lyrics" or "Explicit content". I'm interested in how they settled upon this wording: "explicit" seems like an odd word to use compared to say "graphic" or "vulgar".

Comment: because it’s explicit rather than implicit.

Comment: But what would be an example of implicit lyrics?

Comment: If the question truly is "how they settled" on this wording, it's a political solution to a political problem with multiple stakeholders, and ought to be asked at/migrated to politics.se.  This external story details some of the negotiations involved https://www.npr.org/sections/therecord/2010/10/29/130905176/you-ask-we-answer-parental-advisory---why-when-how

Comment: “Laying next to me, Sharing our love between the sheets”

Comment: Do you realize that "explicit" is synonymous with "vulgar" and "graphic" (and this was also the case in the 80s)? Are you essentially looking for the etymology?

Comment: Because it's sufficiently non-explicit to not alarm the thought police.

Answer (score 2):

Implicit would be like "Rubbing sticks and stones together makes the sparks ignite / Looking forward to a little afternoon delight" or "Mama's got a squeezebox / Daddy never sleeps at night" or "Now you're lying close to me / Giving it to me".